# Finder doesn't starts on Mountain Lion (10.8.2)

Tags: macos, finder, startup, bug

It happens almost every time after startup. When I click on the Finder it tries to start it, the menubar starts, then the desktop icons disappear for a few seconds then they come back, but the finder window never starts.

Sometimes it says when I try to launch it:

> The last time you opened Finder, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?
>
> If you choose not to reopen windows, you may have to open and position the windows yourself.

but otherwise I don't get any errors. The same happens with Chrome too.

I usually fix this by restarting the computer like 7-8 times and sometimes it just works. I already repaired the disk permissions. the verify disk says everything is ok.

What could cause this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are there crash reports in Console.app > System / User Diagnostic Reports? If nothing else works, try doing an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition. It shouldn't affect user files, but it's one of the best troubleshooting steps for issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reset this apps preferences.

- Got to ~/Library/Preferences
- Search this folder for files that contain `finder` in its' names.
- Delete them
- logout and login back

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me

https://support.filetransporter.com/article/AA-00398

1. Cick the Finder icon in the Dock.
2. From the Go menu, choose Utilities.
3. Open the Terminal app.
4. Type: sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force
5. Press Return.
6. When prompted, enter your OS X user password, and press Return.